# CRM C# Close Quote Request : "An unexpected error occurred."

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to close the quote in a plugin and I am sure that the quote's status(statecode) is active(not draft).I am using Close Quote Request Message as shown below.

```
        CloseQuoteRequest closeQuoteRequest = new CloseQuoteRequest()
        {
             QuoteClose=quote,
             Status=new OptionSetValue(5)
        };

       service.Execute(closeQuoteRequest);
```

When i execute the request, it throws error message:'An unexpected error occurred'. 
Then I found another approach but in that approach, I cant use CloseQuote class under Crm.Sdk.Messages namespace.

```
 CloseQuoteRequest closeQuoteRequest = new CloseQuoteRequest()
 {
    QuoteClose = new QuoteClose()
    {
       QuoteId = closeQuote.ToEntityReference(),
       Subject = "Accepted " + DateTime.Now.ToString()
    },

   Status = new OptionSetValue(5),
  };
```

How can I use QuoteClose class or what's wrong with first code block that cause an error?

Comment: Try to set the State and the Status, not only the Status.

Comment: There is no property in CloseQuoteRequest  class for state. That request will close the quote so close value for statecode will be automatically set.

Comment: You right, but in late bound, QuoteClose is an Entity, so you need to pass a Guid to QuoteId, not an entity reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood in first code part you were passing quote entity instance to QuoteClose parameter of Request. This is wrong because you have to pass QuoteClose entity instance. Recheck following article - http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2011/08/close-quote-using-jscript-or-net-in.html